# Google Sheets script that produces the time, date, and user of the last time the document was changed

Tags: google-sheets

When I run the script I get the error "TypeError: Cannot find function getLastUpdated in object Sheet.
getLastModified @ Code.gs:3"

```
function getLastModified() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastModified = sheet.getLastUpdated();
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var timeZone = Session.getTimeZone();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(lastModified, timeZone, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  var message = "Last modified by " + user + " on " + formattedDate;
  sheet.getRange("I1").setValue(message);
}
```

I am trying to run a script to automaitcally return a message in cell I1 when the sheet is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error your'e getting is because `getLastUpdated()` is not a valid method for a [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) class. You should use the [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) function as it's an event and just grab your data.

Example:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rightNow = new Date();
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var timeZone = Session.getTimeZone();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(rightNow, timeZone, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  var message = "Last modified by " + user + " on " + formattedDate;
  sheet.getRange("I1").setValue(message);
}
```

Comment: You are awesome my friend! It worked! I appreciate you :)